# how to do to update (or set) an extension mime_type of file if the mime type is modified by an user in drive google or if different of "PNG"?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, mime-types

I am working to transfer the file image from folder A of google drive to the other folder B of that same parent of google drive and convert the file extension as `mime_type="PNG"` and place it in folder B. Because, I would like to keep the SAME url but inside THAT url, the image changes. For example, the pub image changes according to the period like a "**happy new year**" image for 3 weeks to display it and after this period, it takes other image as default

I noticed a problem for the file extension using a function:

```
      var Mime_Type=file.getMimeType();
```

here, Mime_Type="jpeg"

While the extension of a file name is PNG that the user renames in a google drive!
see screenshot (breakpoint).

```js
function chercherimage()
{
 Logger.log('Debut chercherimage() ');      

  //** aller chercehr l'image publicitaire 
     // publicité à recuperer
//  var pub_image ="O";
//  var Val_Pub_image =" "; 
//  var arrayobjet = Pub(pub_image);
//  var textvalue = arrayobjet;
//  
//  var myObject = {"Pub":textvalue };   
//  var myJson = JSON.stringify(myObject);
//  Logger.log("Recuperation_image_Pub_V1 - text :"+textvalue);
//  Logger.log("Recuperation_image_Pub_V1- myobjet :"+myObject);
//  Logger.log("Recuperation_image_Pub_V1- myJson :"+myJson);
// 
//  Logger.log('Recuperation_image_Pub_V1 - fin function doGet'); 

    //**  n°fichier trouvé concernant l'image publicitaire

     var FilePub_Name ="images.png";
    
    var folder_name ="pub";
    
    var parent_id = "1IbkJgQjUGvQ6LdX2DX7MzTRnDZv-RrhL";
    var parent_name ="divers";
    
   var Grd_parent_id = "0ADqn6SKzPjeWUk9PVA";
   var Grd_parent_name ="images_partage";
  
    // Get folder by id
     var folderIter = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folder_name);
     
     var Dossier = folderIter.next();
     var Id_Dossier = Dossier.getId()
     Logger.log('Dossier  :'+Dossier.getName() );
     
     var filesIter  = Dossier.getFiles();
     
     var i = 0;
     var flag ="N";   
     while(filesIter.hasNext())
     {
     i++;
     var file = filesIter.next();
     var file_id = file.getId();
     var filename = file .getName();
   
     if (filename ==FilePub_Name )
     {     var flag ="O"; 
             Logger.log('file_id trouvé  :'+file_id );
             
             var filesize = file .getSize();
             Logger.log('filename  :'+filename);
             Logger.log('filesize   :'+filesize );
             
             var Mime_Type=file.getMimeType();
             var fileType = getFileType(Mime_Type);
             Logger.log('Mime_Type 1 :'+Mime_Type );
             Logger.log('fileType 1  :'+Mime_Type );
             
               var data = file.getBlob();
             
             var PNG ="png";
             var testSplit= filename.split(".");
             
             if ((testSplit[1] == PNG  ) && (Mime_Type != "images.png"))
             {   Logger.log('Mime_Type  <> PNG  ==> Mime_Type  :'+Mime_Type );
             
           
//  how to force to update (or set) a corrected mime_type "PNG " in the content of this file ?
// I tried using drive.file.update. It doesn't work .
             }
             
            var data = file.getBlob();
            Logger.log('data   :'+data );
            
            var parm_info =[folder_name,Id_Dossier, file_id, filename, filesize , file , data, Mime_Type  ];
            
           // lancer pour remplacer le contenu de l'image dans le drive pub partage
           remplace_file(parm_info);
           break;
       
        }
     }
return parm_info ;
 Logger.log('Fin chercherimage() ');    
}

function remplace_file(parm_info)
{
// ces variables trouvées
var folder_name_source = parm_info[0];
var Id_Dossier_source = parm_info[1];
var file_id_source = parm_info[2];
var filename_source = parm_info[3];
var filesize_source = parm_info[4];  
var file_source  =parm_info[5];
var data_source  =parm_info[6];
var Mime_Type_source = parm_info[7];  

// preparation pour remplacer le contenu de ces variables dans le lien partagé
// aller chercher le dossier partagé : image_partagé

//  var folder_parent_name ="images_partage";
   
  var parentFolderId = "0ADqn6SKzPjeWUk9PVA";
  var parentFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(parentFolderId );
  var parentFolder_Name = parentFolder.getName();
  
  var folders = parentFolder.getFolders();
  var folder;
// iterate through folders in the folders fetched from parent folder
   while (folders.hasNext()) {
    folder = folders.next();
    
    var folder_name;
    // get folder name
    if (folder.getName() == "pubpartage")
    {
    var folder_url = folder.getUrl()
    var folder_id = folder.getId();
    var folder_name =folder.getName();
    Logger.log(folder.getName());    
    Logger.log(folder.getUrl());
    Logger.log(folder.getId());
    
    break;
    }

}

if ( folder_name =="pubpartage")
{ var folderIter = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folder_name);
     
  var Dossier_partage = folderIter.next();
  var Id_Dossier = Dossier_partage .getId();

  Logger.log('Dossier_partage   :'+Dossier_partage .getName() );

 var filesIter  =Dossier_partage.getFiles();
 
 var i=0;
      while(filesIter.hasNext())
     {
     i++;
     var file = filesIter.next();
     
     var file_name = file.getName();
     var file_id = file.getId();
    // var mimeType = Mime_Type_source;
     
     var mimeType = file.getMimeType(); 
     Logger.log('file_id partage :'+file_id );
     Logger.log('file_name partage :'+file_name );
     Logger.log('mimeType  partage :'+mimeType  );
     
      // à remplacer les contenus des données ...   
     if (file_name =="test_pub.png")
     { var file_test_2 ={
        title: file_name,
        mimeType: mimeType ,
        driveId: Id_Dossier,
        parents: parentFolderId
           }
           
         Drive.Files.update(file_test_2 ,file_id , data_source, {supportsAllDrives:true});
         break;
     }

    }
    
    
  }  
}
```

[image]

After processing "using drive; file.update" the image shown in google drive does not change but when I click on that file image then it opens. He sees that the image changes. It means that for me, the value of the content, as an image, changes.
So how to force the change of the mime type: PNG instead of JPG or other types outside of PNG, to allow viewing the image of the file in google drive?

Comment: Is that the entire script you are using? Could you modify it and add comments to differentiate which folder is which? (folder A, folder B, etc)

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Do you want to change the mimeType of the image? Or, do you want to give the extension to the unknown images (PNG or JPEG)?

Comment: to yancy and tanaike, see my answer below . thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps, you don't understand my explication in above . because , my level in english is average . Sincerely sorry . I prefer to write you more clear and to attach my draw to help you to understand better ...

First of all, the extension of the "PNG" image file, placed in folder B, always remains and NEVER changes. This file name is "testpub.png".

I would like to check the extension of file IN the folder A before starting to copy the contents of the image file, using DRIVE.FILE.UPDATE.

1. If the image file extension "PNG" appeared in folder A AND Mime_type is "image/png", it works for copying the image content of the file in folder A to the file in folder B , named "testpub.png" using the "DRIVE.FILE.UPDATE" function. Here it's OK
2. If the image file extension, other than "PNG" (eg JPG, GIF etc...), appeared in folder A AND Mime_type is different from "image/png" (eg:"image /GIF" or "image/JPG" etc...) , it doesn't work for copying image content of file in folder A to file in folder B , named "testpub.png" using the "DRIVE.FILE.UPDATE" function.

Because, the file extension of folder A is not the same as that of folder B .
So, here the user renames "manually" to change the file extension "PNG" instead of the other extension ("JPG","GIF" etc...) .

It partially works, using DRIVE.FILE.UPDATE.

Result: after processing using DRIVE.FILE.UPDATE , we see that , in folder B, the small image, like the icon, of the file "testpub.png" in google drive, "does not change **BUT,** after clicking on this icon there, the content of this file changes.

Because, the RENAMED file ".....PNG" of folder A, made by the user, did appear in folder A **but**, in the content of THIS file there, the extension does not change and it is different of "PNG"!

The problem to solve: I would like the image, like the icon, of the file in folder B, to be identical with the real image (after clicking this icon and the file extension (Mime_type) MUST automatically rename " PNG" instead of the old extension if the user renames the "PNG" extension of the file in folder A

See my attached draw below
[image]

Comment: Ok, what I understand is:

Having two folders (folderA and folderB). If FolderA contains a non PNG file, you want to change its mimetype to PNG so it can later be copied over to folderB, right now with drive.file.update it is not working.

Is the above correct?

Comment: to yancy Godoy, yes correct, he must also modify the mime type in the content of this file, everything is at the same time if the user enters by modifying the file extension of the icon